# Geoserver SLD for OSM valdation errors

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, sld

I'm trying to build a Geoserver (V2.0.2) style file for OSM data using https://github.com/FlorentDotMe/OSM-Styles-for-GeoServer as a starting point but they produce a number of validation errors

Can some one suggest where I'm going wrong or where I can get a valid style file for OSM data (Points, Lines and Polygons)?

This is what i've done to date.
According to this blog you can ignore these http://guanxiaoyu.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/florentdotmes-osm-sld-for-geoserver.html

and previewing the separate layers works however grouping the layers together Lines on top of polygons & then attempt to preview the group doesn't work the file save to dialogue box is shown indicating an error I'm  assuming is related to the validation errors

following the instructions in this comment http://blog.geoserver.org/2009/01/30/geoserver-and-openstreetmap/#comment-76354
I've attempted to fix the style_osm_line but I'm still getting loads of errors

so I've created a smaller manageable sub file to work out how it works, I'm aware it is very incomplete. I get the following errors.

Errors

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Filter'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/sld":Name, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":Title, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":Abstract, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":LegendGraphic, "http://www.opengis.net/ogc":Filter, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":ElseFilter, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":MinScaleDenominator, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":MaxScaleDenominator, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":Symbolizer}' is expected.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Filter'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/sld":Name, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":Title, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":Abstract, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":LegendGraphic, "http://www.opengis.net/ogc":Filter, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":ElseFilter, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":MinScaleDenominator, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":MaxScaleDenominator, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":Symbolizer}' is expected.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Filter'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/sld":Name, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":Title, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":Abstract, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":LegendGraphic, "http://www.opengis.net/ogc":Filter, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":ElseFilter, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":MinScaleDenominator, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":MaxScaleDenominator, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":Symbolizer}' is expected.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'ogc:Or' is not complete. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/ogc":comparisonOps, "http://www.opengis.net/ogc":spatialOps, "http://www.opengis.net/ogc":logicOps}' is expected.
```

SLD File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> <StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
     <Name>style_osm_line</Name>
    <UserStyle>
    <Title>'Line'</Title>
    <!--TAG-->
    <FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Rule>
    <Filter>
      <ogc:Or>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>highway</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>footway</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>highway</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>pedestrian</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>highway</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>path</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>highway</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>steps</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Or>
    </Filter>
  
    <MinScaleDenominator>1000</MinScaleDenominator>
    <MaxScaleDenominator>12500</MaxScaleDenominator>
    <LineSymbolizer>
      <Stroke>
        <CssParameter name="stroke">#A20808</CssParameter>
        <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
        <CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray">1 3</CssParameter>
        <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
        <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
        <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">0.5</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
    </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    </FeatureTypeStyle>
   <FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Rule>
    <Filter>
    <ogc:Or>
      <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>highway</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>unclassified</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>highway</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>road</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>highway</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>residential</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>highway</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>unsurfaced</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>highway</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>living_street</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    </ogc:Or>
    </Filter>
    <MinScaleDenominator>1000</MinScaleDenominator>
    <MaxScaleDenominator>12500</MaxScaleDenominator>
    <TextSymbolizer>
      <Label>
        <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
      </Label>
      <Font>
        <CssParameter name="font-family">Lucida Sans</CssParameter>
        <CssParameter name="font-size">10</CssParameter>
        <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
        <CssParameter name="font-weight">normal</CssParameter>
      </Font>
      <LabelPlacement>
      <LinePlacement />
      </LabelPlacement>
      <Halo>
        <Radius>1</Radius>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#ffffff</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
      </Halo>
      <Fill>
        <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
        <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1.0</CssParameter>
      </Fill>
      <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>
      <VendorOption name="group">yes</VendorOption>
      <VendorOption name="spaceAround">0</VendorOption>
      <VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">300</VendorOption>
      <VendorOption name="repeat">750</VendorOption>
    </TextSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    </FeatureTypeStyle>
    <FeatureTypeStyle>
      <Rule>
      <Filter>
      <ogc:Or><ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>highway</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>tertiary</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo></ogc:Or>
      </Filter>
      <MinScaleDenominator>1000</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>12500</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
        <CssParameter name="stroke">#bbbbba</CssParameter>
        <CssParameter name="stroke-width">10</CssParameter>
        <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
        <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
      </Rule>
    </FeatureTypeStyle>

    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: You may be assuming to much (when you say the error must be due to the validation errors). Please look in the geoserver logs and provide the full stack trace that pops up when you get the error, or else, turn on "verbose exceptions" in the "global" section and then attach the full error text you get (it's going to be very long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error messages are quite clear:

> content was found starting with element 'Filter'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/sld":Name, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":Title, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":Abstract, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":LegendGraphic, "http://www.opengis.net/ogc":Filter, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":ElseFilter, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":MinScaleDenominator, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":MaxScaleDenominator, "http://www.opengis.net/sld":Symbolizer}' is expected

If you look through the list of expected elements you will see "http://www.opengis.net/ogc":Filter where as you have sld:Filter (though the sld: is implied) so change Filter to ogc:Filter to fix.

For the remaining error:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'ogc:Or' is not complete. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/ogc":comparisonOps, "http://www.opengis.net/ogc":spatialOps, "http://www.opengis.net/ogc":logicOps}' is expected.

This implies one of the Or filters is broken, I can't see exactly what is wrong in the box above but it's probably a typo or a capitalisation problem.